# UserScript для Лиги 17

Tags: javascript, html, userjs

Приветствую `%alluser%`
Есть браузерная игра [Лига 17](http://league17.ru).
Хотелось бы написать к ней скрипт для [tampermonkey](https://tampermonkey.net/), в игре есть "Питомник Лиги" [вот код этого блока](http://pastebin.com/77Q7wtZk).
Задача вывести список всех покимонов, если возможно то и сортировку прикрутить.
Я думал сделать в подобном виде.

```
var enemyDiv = document.getElementById('divFarmList');
while ( x )
{
var enemyImage = enemyDiv.getElementsByClassName('image');
var enemyName = enemyDiv.getElementsByClassName('name');
var enemyLvL = enemyDiv.getElementsByClassName('lvl');
var enemyIvcode = enemyDiv.getElementsByClassName('ivcode');
}
```

Но во первых так работать не будет но и проблема в том что выводится не весь список поков разом а по 25 за раз.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Могли бы привести эту кашу на pastebin и к нормальному виду, а то смотреть туда невозможно. Если Вам лень это делать, то потенциальным отвечающим и подавно. Неужели так сложно воспользоваться любым онлайн инструментом автоматического форматирования(html beatifier)?

Работать код будет нормально, что вам не нравится?

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".divFarmPoke")
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
    var pokeinfo = "";
   pokeinfo += " image src: " + elements[i].querySelector(".image").src;
    pokeinfo += " name: " +  elements[i].querySelector(".name").innerText;
    pokeinfo += " lvl: " + elements[i].querySelector(".lvl").innerText;
    pokeinfo += " ivcode: " + elements[i].querySelector(".ivcode").innerText;
    console.log(pokeinfo)
}
```

```html
        <div id="divFarmList" class="">
            <div class="divFarmPoke">
                <div class="button ctrl nobg btnBack">
                </div>
                <div class="pokemonBoxTiny sizeundefined clickable">
                    <img class="image" src="//img.league17.ru/pub/pkmn/norm/anim/298.gif">
                    <div class="name">
                        #298 Азурилл
                    </div>
                    <div class="shorts">
                        <span class="sex1 breedable">♂</span><span class="lvl">6</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="extra">
                        <span><span class="ivcode">h0a24d9s21sa12sd26.100G</span></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="hr">
            </div>
            <div class="divFarmPoke">
                <div class="button ctrl nobg btnBack">
                </div>
                <div class="pokemonBoxTiny sizeundefined clickable">
                    <img class="image" src="//img.league17.ru/pub/pkmn/norm/anim/298.gif">
                    <div class="name">
                        #298 Азурилл
                    </div>
                    <div class="shorts">
                        <span class="sex2 breedable">♀</span><span class="lvl">6</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="extra">
                        <span><span class="ivcode">h8a13d12s23sa7sd6.100A</span></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="hr">
            </div>
            <div class="divFarmPoke">
                <div class="button ctrl nobg btnBack">
                </div>
                <div class="pokemonBoxTiny sizeundefined clickable">
                    <img class="image" src="//img.league17.ru/pub/pkmn/norm/anim/118.gif">
                    <div class="name">
                        #118 Голдин
                    </div>
                    <div class="shorts">
                        <span class="sex1 breedable">♂</span><span class="lvl">12</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="extra">
                        <span><span class="ivcode">h8a6d26s3sa4sd11.100G</span></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="hr">
            </div>
        </div>
```

По поводу того, что код выводит не всех, то что Вы хотите? Он выводит только то, что есть на странице. Нужно всех, грузите остальные страницы и парсите их. Либо через Ajax, либо через ручные переходы.

В любом случае, не забывайте про правила и в случае использования сторонних программ-ботов возможно Вас ждет бан, причем как вариант целой IP подсети: [Лига 17: правила](http://league17.ru/rules)

Comment: Большое спасибо! Про html beatifier я не знал, самому не удобно.